# Drawing an anti-aliased trapezoid

Tags: graphics, antialiasing

I'm trying to draw an anti-aliased trapezoid by starting at the top and drawing line by line. When the line is not an integer number of pixels the end-pixels are weighted average of the background greylevel and the trapezoid greylevel, e.g. if a line is 128.5 pixels long then at each end, the grey-level is:

> ```
>     0.25*(trapezoid_greylevel)+0.75*(background_greylevel)
> ```

Unfortunately the result is not very smooth (I've checked this on a linearised display):

[image: Jagged trapezoid]

I assume that at each line-end I need to take into account **all** the pixels surrounding it to arrive at an appropriate grey-level, but I can't work out how to do it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a trapezoid is convex, it is easy to classify points with respect to a trapezoid: a point is inside iff it is to the left of all trapezoid edges (assuming the trapezoid to oriented counterclockwise).

Assuming square pixels (and a trapezoid larger than a pixel), you can then easily classify pixels with respect to a trapezoid by classifying their corners: if all four corners are outside, then the pixel is outside; if all four corners are inside, then the pixel is inside. For the other pixels, you can do antialiasing by supersampling.

You can also do adaptive rendering by using a quadtree as in [Warnock's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warnock_algorithm) but you'll have to implement a more robust intersection test for a square against a 
 trapezoid (or a convex polygon in general). You only need to detect when a square and the trapzoid are disjoint or when a square is inside the trapezoid. The depth of the quadtree beyond the pixel level will determine how fine the antialiasing is.

Finally, you can also do *exact* rendering by computing the percentage of a pixel's area covered by the trapezoid. It's a matter of polygon clipping and you can use the [Sutherland–Hodgman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman).

Comment: @Robs, if you end up implementing any of this, I'd like to see the images and the code, if you can share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution if speed is not an issue is to draw a non-antialiased trapezoid at 4 or 8 times the resolution and then linearly scale down the image.